# JPA ManyToMany join table automatically set index unique

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

Still quite new to JPA here and battled with a problem for almost two days, seeking help.

My project uses Spring Data and MySql, currently there is a very simple schema with User, Group entities.

```
@Entity
public class User {

public User() {}

public User(String username, boolean superUser, boolean blackList) {
    this.username = username;
    this.superUser = superUser;
    this.blackList = blackList;
}

@Id
String username;


public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

...

@ManyToMany
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name="user_groups",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_NAME", referencedColumnName="USERNAME")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="GROUPNAME")})
List<UserGroup> userGroups;

public void addGroup(UserGroup group) {
    if (!this.userGroups.contains(group)){
        this.userGroups.add(group);
    }
}
}
```

And the join table `user_groups` created in DB has indexes for both `user_name` and `groupname`, however `groupname`'s index is a UK_*** and marked with UNIQUE, thus I cannot add `groupA, userA`, `groupA, userB` as it'll complain violation of unique key.

I want to make it the combination of the two values the unique key of the join table, so is there any specific config I'm missing here or I used it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turned out I was making a rookie mistake on JPA that missed getter and setter for this `userGroups` field. By adding them the table is working as expected now.